# How to map geographical data from dataframe on map?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, geolocation, geospatial

I have a dataframe:

```
city              longitude   latitude     val
New-York         -74.006015   40.712728     10
Chicago          -87.624421   41.875562     15
Los-Angeles      -118.242766  34.053691     8
```

I want to map dots on map of USA on those coordinates, where size of the dot depends on value on column "val". How could I do that? I tried to use geoviews library, but is uses bokeh but i need just a snapshot.

Comment: This might help : https://towardsdatascience.com/easy-steps-to-plot-geographic-data-on-a-map-python-11217859a2db

Comment: You can look at this : https://python-visualization.github.io/folium/quickstart.html

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, try `contextily` and `geopandas` library.

On Windows 10, contextily  rise error "connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time"

I used Linux Ubuntu which had no problem connecting to the server returning the base map:

```
import geopandas as gpd
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import contextily as ctx


df = pd.DataFrame({
    'city': ['New-York', 'Chicago', 'Los-Angeles', 'Miami'],
    'longitude': [-74.006015, -87.624421, -118.242766, -80.13 ],
    'latitude': [40.712728, 41.875562, 34.053691, 25.47], 'val': [10, 15, 8, 40]
     })
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(
    df, geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(df.longitude, df.latitude))

# deal with crs
gdf.set_crs(epsg=4326, inplace=True)
map_df = gdf.to_crs(epsg=3857)

# set size of markers
ax = map_df.plot(markersize=map_df['val'])

# extend size map to USA 
extent = (-14000000, -7800000, 2000000, 6000000)
ax.axis(extent)

# add USA base map 
# the line with which Windows 10 had a problem
ctx.add_basemap(ax, source=ctx.providers.OpenStreetMap.Mapnik)
```

As a result, we get a snapshot:

[image]